# Implicit Differentiation. Please help me understand why!

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I am trying to understand implicit differentiation; I understand what to do (that is no problem), but why I do it is another story. For example:

$$3y^2=5x^3 $$

I understand that, if I take the derivative with respect to x of both sides of the equation, I'll get:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(3y^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(5x^3)$$
$$6y\frac{d}{dx}(y)=15x^2\frac{d}{dx}(x)$$
$$6y\frac{dy}{dx}=15x^2\frac{dx}{dx}$$
$$6y\frac{dy}{dx}=15x^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{15x^2}{6y}$$

Unless I made some sort of error, this is what I am suppose to do. But why? Specifically, on the second line, I utilize the chain rule for the "outer function" and get 6y, but I still need to utilize the chain rule for the "inner function" which is the y. So why don't I go ahead and take the derivative of y and get 1? I know that I am not suppose to, but I don't really "get it." It seems to me that I only use the chain rule "halfway". Why isn't it an all or nothing? If it's all done with respect to x, it would seem to me that the 3y^2 should remain unchanged entirely.

This is my problem. And I apologize if I got some of the terminology wrong.

Comment: "Why don't I ... take the derivative of $y$ and get $1$?" You do take the derivative of $y$ but you don't get $1$.  If you were differentiating with respect to $y$, then you'd get $dy/dy=1$, but you're differentiating with respect to $x$.  (If you really wanted to differentiate the left side of the equation with respect to $y$, then you'd have to also differentiate the right side with respect to $y$. You can't differentiate one side with respect to $x$ and the other with respect to $y$. You have to do the same thing to both sides of the equation.)

Comment: You could continue to get $y' y' + y y'' = 5 x$ - but it is unclear what your problem actually is...

Comment: @John, actually $y$ is not a function of $x$ - or at least it is multi-valued.

Comment: @johannesvalks, fair enough, I've removed my comment in order not to cause too much confusion.

Comment: @Andreas I understand the idea of differentiating with respect to x (or at least, I think I do). I think my issue is that I am not sure why, if it's all done with respect to x, that I am messing with the 3y^2 at all. Why does it become 6y?

Comment: @user263961, well $\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}$ put in $z = 3y^2$ so $\frac{dz}{dy} = 6 y$ and so you get $\frac{dz}{dx} = 6 y \frac{dy}{dz}$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:Even though the previous comment is the best justification for this question is it right to differentiate $3y^2$ using $x$ when we can't even see an $x$ in $3y^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}$ *may* equal $1$ in special cases, but it is not generally so.   The very point of implicit derivation is that you *don't know* what it *is*.

So, the Chain Rule is used to separate the derivative of a function of $y$ wrt $x$ into two differential terms, one you can resolve, and one unknown.

To be clear, here's the process with the stage added and highlighted. Does this help?
$$\begin{align}
3y^2&=5x^3
\\[1ex]
\frac{\mathrm d(3y^2)}{\mathrm d x} &= \frac{\mathrm d(5x^3)}{\mathrm dx}
& \text{Take the derivative w.r.t. }x
\\[1ex]
\color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm d(3y^2)}{\mathrm d y}\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}}&=\frac{\mathrm d(5x^3)}{\mathrm dx}
& \text{Apply the Chain Rule to the L.H.S.}
\\[1ex]
6y\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}&=15x^2
& \text{Evaluate the polynomial derivatives }\frac{\mathrm d(c\,z^n)}{\mathrm d z}=c\,n\,z^{n-1} \\ && \text{where }n\in\Bbb N,\text{ and }c\text{ is constant}
\\[1ex]
\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}&=\frac{5x^2}{2y}
& \text{Use arthimetic rearrangement}
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, we might use *explicit* differentiation, as follows:
$$\begin{align}
3y^2&=5x^3
\\[1ex]
y & = x^{3/2}\,\sqrt{\frac 5 3\;} & \star
\\[1ex]
\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x} & = \frac{\mathrm d x^{3/2}}{\mathrm d x}\;\sqrt{\frac 5 3\;}
\\[1ex]
~ & = \frac{3 x^{1/2}\sqrt 5}{2\sqrt 3}
\\[1ex]
~ & = \frac{3 x^{1/2}\sqrt 5}{2\sqrt 3}\times\frac{x^{3/2}\sqrt 5}{y\sqrt 3}
& \text{ re: }\star
\\[1ex]
~ & = \frac{5x^2}{2y}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Change $y$ to $y(x)$ and everything should be clear. $y$ is not a constant, but a function of $x$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}y(x)=y'(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

For a concrete example, let $y(x)=x^2$. Clearly $y'=2x$. However, per the question, lets consider $y^2=x^4$.

Say you wanted to find $y'$. Then:

$$\frac{d}{dx} y^2=4x^3$$
$$2yy'=4x^3$$
$$y'=\frac{4x^3}{2y}=\frac{4x^3}{2x^2}=2x$$

Which is good! However:

$$2y=4x^3$$

is patently not true and even worse, doesn't contain $y'$, which is the entire point of this!